# Adding complicated INDEX formula results in Excel file error

Tags: excel, openxml-sdk

I have a problem inserting this formula in Excel spreadsheet using OpenXML SDK.

```
=INDEX(Codes[[#All];[code1:]];MATCH(MySheet!B1674;Codes[[#All];[code2:]];0))
```

I've been doing this just by adding text into a cell using method like this:

```
private Cell ConstructCellFormula(string formula)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        CellFormula cFormula = new CellFormula();
        cFormula.Text = formula;
        cell.Append(cFormula);
        return cell;
    }
```

I know that I'm missing something in calling this.

The spreadsheet that I'm working on is a part of many in XLSM file.

> Codes

is also there.

What I'm doing is - I remove all existing rows and add new based on data from the database. That's when problems with the file start.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it in EN-US syntax with commas instead of semi-colons?

Comment: @Jeeped no I haven't. Can you please tell me how to set syntax for this?

Comment: Change all semi-colons to commas.

Comment: My man you're a genius :D It worked I would never think about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to simply use `EN-US` syntax with commas instead of semi-colons.

`=INDEX(Codes[[#All],[code1:]],MATCH(MySheet!B1674,Codes[[#All],[code2:]],0))`